# Temporary SQL datafield

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Currently I am returning a boolean value as "1" or "0" or value of a column let say column A in one of my stored procedure and it works perfectly, however in one of application I am trying to get value like this

```
string temp = reader.TryGetValue("ColumnA", out licenseStatus) ? temp : string.Empty;
```

Stored procedure is doing something like this,

```
if @datafield = 1
    return 1
else if @datafield = 2 AND @datafield2 = 3
    return 0
else
    return (SELECT ColumnA.table2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id and table2.id Where @datafield3 = 0)
```

Now I want to return result as value of ColumnA always instead of sending "0" or "1" as I am not allowed to make changes to code in application.

Is it possible ? I can't make any changes to ColumnA value at all either.

**EDIT**

> I already mentioned in my question that stored procedure is doing what
>   its suppose to do but not working with my code, as I am returning 1 or
>   0 at some point and my code isn't getting it as columnA so its setting
>   it up empty, I want to return 0 or 1 as value of ColumnA but at same
>   time I don't want to change value of columnA in table2..
>
> :)

Comment: Do you must have to use the last else query. Otherwise you can use case answered below

Comment: yup I must have to use query but I can create a new datafield which will be getting value from the query, but main problem is I don't want to change value of ColumnA in table2 at all

Comment: Is the whole procedure an insert query. If it is not then the code you've posted does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if @datafield = 1
set ColumnA.table2=1
else if @datafield = 2 AND @datafield2 = 3
set ColumnA.table2= 0
else
return (SELECT ColumnA.table2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id and table2.id Where @datafield3 = 0)
```

If it is only a select query then it will not change your table data rather it'll return what you want

Comment: cheers thanks, but while setting that datafield it needs to return it as well, not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`

```
select 
    case @datafield 
    when 1 then 1 
    when 2 then 0 
    when 3 then 0 
    else ColumnA 
    end as ColumnA
from ....
```

Comment: will it gonna change value of ColumnA in table tho ?