# Does select query change column data value if we use "set" in it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In reference to my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176567/temporary-sql-datafield/13177257#13177257) someone said in select query if I set a column data value for a table it won't going to update columns value in my table within a stored procedure, is that's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. Select query will only return you that value, it will not update the data in table.

Answer (score 1):

Select query cannot be used to set column values, you can use update statement for that purpose.
But you can set variable values like:
`declare @i int, @j int

select @i=1, @j=2`

So it will work there but not on table columns.