# How to set and return a column Value in SQL Stored Procedure within If else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In reference to my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176567/temporary-sql-datafield/13177257#13177257) I am not sure how can I set and then return a column data value with out saving it to table.

```
if @datafield = 1
set ColumnA.table2=1
else if @datafield = 2 AND @datafield2 = 3
set ColumnA.table2= 0
else
return (SELECT ColumnA.table2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id and table2.id Where @datafield3 = 0)
```

I am not sure how to return after setting values, I did tried begin and end , not working tho

Comment: 1. I think your `inner join` syntax is incorrect
2. Do you have only one row in table1? If not - you'll get a random row from that table

Comment: @RomanPekar sorry I changed syntax so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: is that change work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest thing you can do to return value

```
Declare @returnvalue int

if @datafield = 1
   set @returnvalue=1
else if @datafield = 2 AND @datafield2 = 3
set @returnvalue= 0
else
     SELECT @returnvalue=ColumnA.table2 FROM table1
        INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id and table2.id 
        Where @datafield3 = 0

 select @returnvalue as ColumnA
 return @returnvalue
```

Comment: Would Love to do that but I must have to return data as ColumnA, otherwise one of app created by someone else won't going to work and I am not allowed to change it :(

Comment: for this you can just write down select @returnvalue theat will do the select also and dont crash the existing one

Comment: Also modify @returnvalue  variable as output parameter

Comment: @ArunManjhi - there is no need to convert "returnvalue" as output if its int because sql proceudre allows to return value

Comment: @PranayRana but I want my code to send columnA back as in C# code its trying to get value of ColumnA

Comment: @tereško - just write like this "select returnvalue as ColumnA" this will return value as "ColumnA".. this will resolve that issue also